# Getting item from Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am just having one of those days. How can query the "116" in this array and set it to a variable?

```
Array
( 
    [pa_vendor] => Array 
    ( 
         [terms] => Array 
              ( 
                  [0] => 116 
              )
         [query_type] => and
    )
)
```

Comment: You reference it like this: `$value = $array['key']` - you have a multi level array and will need to add multiple keys though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

let the array is `$arr`.

```
echo $variable_store = $arr['pa_vendor']['terms'][0]; //116
```

Comment: That worked. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

$NewVariableName = $terms[0];

See:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php6p3.html

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 0):

Your array splits like this

Your array has one element, this is the element with 'pa_vendor' as index.
It can be accessed by using

```
 $arr['pa_vendor']
```

`$arr['pa_vendor']` is een array with two elements
first element has index 'terms' and is an array
second element has index 'query_type' and is a string.
These can be accessed by using

```
$arr['pa_vendor']['terms']
```

and

```
$arr['pa_vendor']['query_type']
```

`$arr['pa_vendor']['terms']` is an array with one element
this element has index '0' and is a number
this element can be accessed by using

```
$arr['pa_vendor']['terms'][0]
```